# Eclipse log debug windows function calls

Tags: eclipse, debugging, logging

I was wondering if there's an option where I can print out the entire content of the debug window in Eclipse.

[image]

You see, if I pause the MCU, the debug window shows the current functions called on the stack. What I need, is to log into file every function that has been called since system start.

Do you guys have any idea how to make it happen?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear to me? You want to save stack or "every function that has been called since system start", because those two are very different things...

Comment: Sorry for not beeing clear. I'd like to log every system call since start up. Is there such a way?

Comment: jstack may help you.

Comment: Nope, it does not lists the functions i want it to.

Comment: @Betlista Do you have any idea how I can manage it?

Answer (score 0):

when you pause, you may call `/jdk1.8/bin/jstack.exe -l 111111 > dump.txt` where `111111` is process id of the application (jvm). when you look at dump.txt you will see the thread dump of the jvm, which also contains what you see at eclipse's debug view